# random effect in mixed linear model SPSS

Tags: mixed-model, spss

I am using a mixed linear model to analyze the effect of two types of treatment on symptoms.  The two treatments were administered in smaller groups (clusters), and delivered by several doctors, so I need to account for clustering (ICC is substantial).  I am using difference in symptom scores from baseline as my outcome measure, treatment type and baseline symptoms (to control for them) as fixed effects, and group cluster and doctor, specified in the 1st level as "subjects" as random (intercept) effects. My model is as follows:

```
MIXED outcome BY treatment WITH baseline_sx
  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(500) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE) 
  /FIXED=treatment baseline_sx | SSTYPE(3) 
  /METHOD=REML 
  /PRINT=G  SOLUTION TESTCOV 
  /RANDOM=INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(doctor*cluster_gr) COVTYPE(VC).
```

For some reason, the model chokes (gives me a warning about the Hessian matrix not being positive definite) and does not produce any estimate for my random effects.  It does just fine for very data from a different outcome point -- the only difference is that some observations are available for one outcome point and not the other, but overall the number of observations is about the same.  I don't think it has anything to do with covariance structure -- tried different kinds, does not seem to solve the problem.  I pretty much narrowed it down to some kind of problem in one of the groups, possibly having to do with cluster variance...  Has anyone encountered anything similar or have any suggestions for how to overcome this issue?

Comment: What are your `doctor` and `cluster_gr` variables? And more generally, what's the nesting structure? Each observation is nested under what variable(s)? I don't understand why you have an interaction between 2 variables in the `SUBJECT()` bit of the `RANDOM` command.

Comment: Are you able to clarify whether you're asking for help with a statistical issue, or simply a software problem?

Comment: Each observation is nested under cluster_gr (i.e. 88 subjects, 12 cluster subgroups, each person in one of the cluster subgroups, cluster subgroups).  Cluster subgroup is nested under doctor (i.e. 5 doctors, 4 administered the treatment to 1 cluster subgroup each, and one administered the treatment to the remaining 8 subgroups).

Comment: I did not intend to specify an interaction between my two random terms, but I think SPSS just does that when you specify random intercepts by putting "subjects" variables into "combinations" box.  It makes sense though, because for each level of doctor, there can be several levels of cluster.  I'm not sure if this matters for the sort of issue I am experiencing, because the problem persists for data from that particular measurement time point regardless of whether I include only one of the random variables or both (I think when I model cluster*doctor, this is treated same as cluster alone).

Comment: ).    Another thing that bothers me a bit the denominator degrees of freedom I get for the data from measurement points on which this model works: it's around 10 (as if only clusters are considered as observations) as opposed to 80-something, if all participant observations are considered. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I think this is probably a statistical issue rather than a software problem, since I am able to get a solution with this model on slightly different data in SPSS.